# if i scale up a service with a bind volume , Docker swarm will create a new bind volume in the second machine ?

Tags: docker-swarm

I created a service in docker swarm with a bind volume in specific path. 
If i scale up ,  will docker  create a new service with a new bind volume (with same path) in the second machine?

Comment: Not enough information, depends on the volume path and driver. If you use the native driver and map multiple nodes/containers to a nfs mounted volume the only concern is file locks, otherwise check out alternative storage drivers that are designed to share a common persistent backed. If you're spinning up multiple processes that require persistence you should be looking into alternative storage options like redis/rabbitmq or postgres or etc....

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Why not just try it and see? This is one of the reasons you usually wouldn't use the default 'local' driver in Swarm. I never recommend bind-mounts in Swarm because it implies something "special" on that node like local/mounted storage configured on the host OS. REX-Ray is a good open-source docker volume driver option, and there are many other volume plugins at [store.docker.com](https://store.docker.com).

Comment: Ok , in my case every node has its disk , volume is mounted in the same path for every node. I prefer bind volumes  because all bind volumes are in a parent folder. So if i need to export data i can make it exporting the parent folder, in the same time every volume is associated to a autoexplicative path so it is simple to work in the volumes also from host.